# How to set the position of a QDialog?

Tags: python, pyqt, qdialog, window-position

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7. I used PyQt to create a dialog, but how to set the position of a `QDialog` object? I tried `self.move(x,y)`, but it does not move and still stays in the original position.

This is my example:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, WindowMixin):

    def __init__(self):
         super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
         self.myDialog = MyDialog(parent=self)

    def createMyDialog(self):
        self.myDialog.popUp(x=self.geometry().x(), y=self.geometry().y(), width=self.geometry().width(), height=self.geometry().height())

class MyDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LabelDialog, self).__init__(parent)

    def popUp(self, x="", y="", width="", height=""):
        if (x!="") and (y!="") and (width!="") and (height!=""):
            # self.resize(width/6, 20)
            self.move(0, 0)
```

I use the `createMyDialog` function to create the modal dialog. Can anyone give any advice?

Comment: show a [mcve]..

Comment: And state which platform you are on.

Comment: ＠ekhumoro I am in ubuntu16.04

Comment: You must provide a [mcve], that piece of code is not complete because it does not help us to reproduce your problem. For example, show how you create a LabelDialog object.

Comment: Is this a modeless or modal dialog? Also, can you be more specific than "does not work"? Does it place the dialog in the wrong place or what?

Comment: @eyllanesc I update the question content

Comment: @eyllanesc yes I did.

Comment: please place a code that you can copy, paste and execute, Your code is not reproducible or complete.